# Attachments sent from server comes screwed with a base64 encrypt text, but when I send from local debugging it went OK

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, devexpress

I'm depared with a sittuation very awkward. I'm sending an e-mail with attachment using `System.Net.Mail`

Here's my code (very simple):

```
public static void Enviar(string assunto, string mensagem, string remetente, string destinatario, Stream anexoFile, string Filename, MailPriority prioridade,string co = "")
{
    try
    {
        string SmtpHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpHost"];
        string SmtpPort = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPort"];
        string SmtpUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpUserName"];
        string SmtpPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPassword"];

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        char[] sep = { ';' };
        string[] to = destinatario.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string para in to)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(para.Trim()))
            {
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(para));
            }
        }

        string[] toco = co.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string para in toco)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(para.Trim()))
            {
                mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(para));
            }
        }
        mail.From = new MailAddress(remetente);
        mail.Subject = assunto;

        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = mensagem;

        mail.Priority = prioridade;

        if (anexoFile != null)
        {
            if (anexoFile.Length > 0)
            {
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(anexoFile, Filename));
            }
        }

        SmtpClient envio = new SmtpClient(SmtpHost, Convert.ToInt32(SmtpPort));
        envio.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SmtpUserName, SmtpPassword);
        envio.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Erro ao enviar o e-mail", e);
    }
}
```

The e-mail is sent well, on local machine and on server, but the attachment, when sent on server comes screwed, a file without extension and with the content encrypted with base64 string. When I sent from my local machine it goes well.

Below is the code that I use to call the `Enviar` method to send the e-mail

```
protected void btnEnviarEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FileName = CadastroRelatorios.getById(Session["idRelatorio"].ToInt()).Nome;

    using (Stream file = new MemoryStream())
    {


        grvExport.WriteXlsx(file);

        file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        string email = "";

        foreach (var mail in Emails)
        {
            email += mail.Address + ";";    
        }

        SMTP.Enviar("Relatório " + FileName, "Você está recebendo esse e-mail do relatório " + FileName + " que foi gerado pelo sistema e enviado por " + Usuario.getById(Convert.ToInt32(Session["CodUsuario"])).Nome, "intranet@mydomain.com", email, file, FileName + ".xlsx", MailPriority.Normal);
    }

}
```

The `grvExport` is a `ASPxGridViewExporter` component from `DevExpress Components` [Component Page](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Exporting/Exporting.aspx)

Someone ever seen this ?

Please help me!

> Edit - Here's a [link to the screwed attachment](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Aw35B6yGtjdFNLaXNuMjliemp5YmFKSjZZVUFWZWdkdWtj/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure your server has the latest patches and updates. This was a known bug in .NET 4.0, but has since been fixed: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2402064. Also make sure this is set to 8bit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.transferencoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'll try it, and let you know the results. Thanks for posting the comment!